# Why the geometries in 32632 projection aren't perfect?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, vector-tiles

I am implementing a Tile Server with the help of PostGIS.

Running this query:

```
                SELECT ST_AsMVT(tile) FROM (
                  SELECT
                    __FEATURES__,
                    ST_AsMVTGeom(
                      ST_Transform(__GEOM__, __SRID__),
                      ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(?, ?, ?), __SRID__),
                      4096,
                      256,
                      false
                    ) as geom
                  FROM __SCHEMA__.__TABLE__
                    WHERE
                    __GEOM__ && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(?, ?, ?), __SRID__)
                ) AS tile
```

In 3857 projection I get a very good result.

But if I use geometries in 32632 I get the borders of the geometries not perfectly aligned and a zig-zag effect.

[image]

Why?

Comment: 3857 is the worst possible projection, useful only because basemap providers use it. If the data is "perfect" in Web Mercator, then it's likely to be useless for most analysis. Please [Edit] the Question to provide a screenshot to better describe your goal here.

Comment: This is likely *not* a backend issue; when you encode geometries referenced in `EPSG:32632` into MVTs, the frontend mapping framework needs to be aware - and *capable* to handle arbitrary projections other than the very common 3857.

Comment: Edited the question with a screenshot.

Comment: What frontend mapping framework *do* you use??

Comment: I'm testing the MVT TIle Server with QGis adding the Vector TIles URLs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue with this query:

```
                SELECT ST_AsMVT(tile) FROM (
                  SELECT
                    __FEATURES__,
                    ST_Transform(ST_AsMVTGeom(
                      ST_Transform(__GEOM__, __PROJ__ __SRID__),
                      ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(?, ?, ?), __PROJ__ __SRID__),
                      4096,
                      512,
                      false
                    ), __PROJ__ __SRID__) as geom
                  FROM __SCHEMA__.__TABLE__
                    WHERE
                    -- Bounding box condition
                    ST_Transform(__GEOM__, __PROJ__ __SRID__) && ST_Transform(ST_TileEnvelope(?, ?, ?), __PROJ__ __SRID__)
                ) AS tile
```

Where `__PROJ__,` is `+proj=utm +zone=32 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs`

Answer (score 0):

[EPSG CODE 32632](https://epsg.io/32632)

Guess this is probably due to the applicability of 32632.

[image]